# Change Icons on Network drives on MacOS, unique Icon for each pc?

Tags: mac, network-shares, icons, finder

This exact question was asked 10 years ago, on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/364683/add-custom-network-device-icons-in-mac-os-x-finder). Unfortunately, the bundle download link is no longer active. I'm not very knowledgeable about this sort of thing so I don't know where to start. I know I can change the resource image in finder, but I want to have different icons for each of my PCs.

Comment: I doubt it will let you mod that file at all on a modern macOS. The previous answer tells you exactly how it was done. You didn't need the ready-made bundle, it was just a convenience. Imagine that if you don't understand the explanation, you're not going to be able to make it work, because it requires you to change each remote machine too.

Comment: Nothing is impossible when it comes to computers. However i guess i don't care enough to spend forever figuring it out, so never mind.